# Build errors saying cannot open any files

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

When I try to build any project I get errors for ALL files saying

`Source file ______ could not be opened -- Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation`

But I have all permissions for these files, and I can read from them and open within VS. Also these are projects I have done no work for, just created new project and build.

I've tried setting reference paths to the folders with the files . Tried deleting bin and obj folders and rebuilding. Also tried deleting the .suo file in the project.

Some notes:

- new install of vs2015, not by me
- do not have admin on computer
- did not install VS 2015 Update 3 (because of no admin access)

Comment: It seems that you are accessing those file from some constructor of any class. Try to disconnect from other processes if they are accessing it like TFS or SVN.

Comment: Would this still be the case if this happens on any project created? I haven't written any code yet, just building it